# How to use nodemailer to send mail from a node js app

Tags: nodemailer

I am creating a web app on node js and jquery. In this app i am using Nodemailer to send emails when use create an account. Right now i am using

```
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
    service: "Gmail",
    auth: {
        user: "abc@gmail.com",
        pass: "abcpws"
    }
});
```

This is working well. But Now i want to change sender email like abc@me.com. Now my email is abc@me.com which is created on (hostgator).

What should i do to use this email to send mail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure the transporter with the SMTP parameters:

```
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host      : 'mail.domain.com',
    port      : 26,
    ignoreTLS: true,
    tls :{rejectUnauthorized: false},
    secure :false,
    auth: {
        user: 'mail@domain.com',
        pass: "123",
    }
});
```